# Word for a zero score in sports -- BrE/ AmE

Tags: word-usage, terminology, american-english, british-english, sports

What would be a word for a zero score in sports in BrE/ AmE?

Suppose, in a game of baseball or football (soccer), a team (Team A) scores one point, but its opponent (Team B) scores none, so Team A wins.  In my experience, in the US, one would usually say "Team A beat Team B one to **nothing**", and the score would be written "Team A 1, Team B 0".  In the UK, on the other hand, one would usually say "Team A beat Team B one - **nil**", and the score would be written "Team A 1 - 0 Team B".  Saying "zero" for 0 when giving scores is, I believe, very rare in both the US and the UK. Do other readers find these observations to be true or mostly true?

Comment: Yes, in the USA, *nothing* is often used as a "substitute" for the number 'zero' in a score of baseball, US football. Also, *zip* is used. So Team A beat Team B 1-nothing or 1-zip; hardy ever 1-zero. In tennis, *love* is used instead of zero.

Comment: Nil in UK, esp for football (soccer). If the game is ongoing "yet to score" is used, too.

Comment: In tennis, a score of 0 is "love," both in the US and in the UK . . .

Comment: Related: [What is the history of “nil” in British football /soccer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167919/what-is-the-history-of-nil-in-british-football-soccer) and [Why do they say “love fifteen,” in tennis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis)

Comment: Also related, and the comments are helpful too: [Are “nil” and “null” interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61363/are-nil-and-null-interchangeable)

Comment: "Nul" or "null" is not interchangeable with "nil" in sports scores.  In other words no "Team A beat Team B one - null".

Comment: Two competing theories of use of the word 'love' for <no score> in tennis are discussed here: https://www.playyourcourt.com/news/what-does-love-mean-tennis/  Of more interest, however, in your question, is why (or how) the order of the opponents' score is announced. This is determined by who is on serve (meaning, who is serving the ball) in a particular game. Thus "Love-15" would mean the person serving has "love" or nothing, and the person being served to has 15. Announcing the score in order of server first is also common in other racquet sports, like squash and racquetball.

Comment: The scoring in lawn tennis (Love, 15, 30, 40, game) is likewise related to its long history in relation to its antecedent, the "indoor tennis" game played by the likes of Henry VIII. But that is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: @tautophile 'Null' is not a substitute for 'nil' or 'zero' in computng either. If you try to compare a variable holding zero and a null variable they won't match.

Answer (score 4):

A Baseball score of zero, when spoken in the US, is never "nil" or "nought," as in other sports in the UK. It may be "zero" or "nothing," the latter probably being more common, but I have routinely heard both, and I am a big baseball fan. Additionally, this is known as a "shutout" in baseball when one of the teams fails to score completely.

Comment: also, zip, as in 5-zip (5 to nothing)

Comment: "Zip" is frequent in US sports talk, but decidedly more informal than "nothing", or "no score".